# Editing gradient in vector image

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a vector image of water. I would like to keep the top wave/bubbles as they are BUT extend the gradient blue on the bottom (to fit the longer length of a trade show banner). I'm sure there's a simple way to do this in Illustrator but I don't know how...

Comment: Example image is a must in this case. Please, provide one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the direct Selection Tool (the White Arrow). To click or shift-click all the anchor points at the bottom of the shape. Then simply click-drag the anchors down to where you want them. You may need to adjust the gradient stops in the Gradient Panel afterwards if the gradient moves too much.

Without a posted sample image, this is the best I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

In Illustrator, the gradient is bound to the shape. So you will most likely have to edit the shape. the setting of the gradient panel will only make changes within the shape.

But we don't know your bubbles nor your trade show banner, so for a more detailed answer, please provide an example.